# Java/LDAP: getAttribute("cn") returns null

Tags: java, ldap

After a search in LDAP, written in Java, I have a valid entry as

```
cn=DE9-M5T,ou=students,ou=users,o=data
```

When I now do

```
if (entry != null && entry.getAttribute("modifyTimestamp") != null) {
         String dn = entry.getDN();
         String modifyTimestamp = entry.getAttribute("modifyTimestamp").getStringValue();
         String oldTimestamp = modificationTimestampCache.get(dn);

         String cnUserId = entry.getAttribute("cn").getStringValue(); 
         ...
 }
```

the last line gives a NullPointerException, which means that

```
entry.getAttribute("cn")
```

must return `null`. Following the documentation, this would only happen if the given attribute (here `"cn"`) could not be found as exact match. Is there any reason that this could happen for `"cn"` in LDAP?

Comment: Can you debug it? I assume that the *entry.getAttribute("modifyTimestamp")* returns more entries than what you intend, which doesn't have the cn. I suggest you to split this line *String cnUserId = entry.getAttribute("cn").getStringValue();* into 2 and add null check. if it is null continue;

Comment: I can't debug this, but sent to the host a version with a null check for entry.getAttribute("cn"); note the null pointer exception is raised for the line for "cn" and not for "modifyTimestamp" (I said so: thge last line gives ...)

Comment: What i meant was that the entry passes the if statement for modifyTimestamp but it doesn't mean *for sure* that it has "cn" attribute. Change the "if" to check also for "cn" attribute like this: `if (entry != null && entry.getAttribute("modifyTimestamp") != null && entry.getAttribute("cn") != null) ` if it works I will publish it as answer and I would appreciate if you would accept it.

Answer (score -1):

From your code I can't figure out the exact types of your entry and its getAttribute(), but consider this:

`cn` is a *multivalued* ldap attribute, where `modifytimestamp` is single valued.

So, the values of `cn` are probably stored in an array-like structure, I guess that your getAttribute() does not handle this as you expect.

Comment: So you are guessing that `getAttribute()` returns null in the case of multivalued attributes? What exactly would be the use of that? And where does it say so in the Javadoc?

Comment: https://www.novell.com/documentation/developer/jldap/jldapenu/api/  check for class LDAPAttributeSet and method getAttribute()

Comment: Check it why? It doesn't support your case. What it says is, and I quote *verbatim,* 'in both cases, `null` is returned if there is no exact match to the specified `attrName`.'  There is exactly nothing there about multivalued attributes.

Comment: I was merely suggesting that multivalued cn could be the issue, as I did not know which java classes were used.

By the way, cn is the naming attribute in the dn.  So you would not expect it to be missing.

Comment: That is *exactly* what you suggested. Your answer has no other content whatsoever, and neither does your response to my comment. By the way, not all object classes have a `cn` attribute, as I already stated some time ago in my own answer. `organizationalUnit` is merely one of many examples.

Comment: Checking the result of entry.getAttribute("cn") against null and ignoring the result in this case, fixes the problem.

Comment: @guru Of course it does: because, for the third time, '*not every object class has a `cn` attribute*', which is what I said my answer, an hour ago.

Comment: As I said in line 2 of my original posting the cn part in the dn is filled and I do not fully understand why asking for it with `entry.getAttribute("cn")` gives null.

Comment: Is it just `cn` that has this issue? What if you try the attribute `objectclass` for example, or `sn` (if that is present)?

Comment: What if access control rules in the directory prohibit you from reading the cn?  I know it sounds very unlikely, as you do have read access to modifytimestamp, but stiil, it might be worth to check.

Comment: I have search with `ldapsearch` for one on those DN and I do get the record as `...\ndn: cn=xxxx,ou=....\nidmEduLibraryNumber: 00000xxxxxx\n ...` (a lot of more attributes follow) but **no** attribute `cn: `

Comment: The LDAP-Admin of the host ack'ed that the `cn` attribute is not provided due to access control rules, which looks strange to me because it is provided as part of the DN. In any case we can close this thread.

Answer (score -1):

Not every object class has a `cn` attribute. Only those where it appears in the schema.

Evidently this isn't one of them.